# Issue with Maximize option in CKEditor Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I have customized my CKEditor of Magnolia with few of the features including maximize.
If i maximize my editor I am not able to include images/Hyperlinks from DAM. It is breaking.But if minimize my Editor then it is working fine. Could you please suggest me?

Thanks in advance,
Vijay Kodali

Comment: Not able how? Buttons disappear or they are not clickable or you get some error when trying to save the dialog? More info and some screenshots would be certainly helpful here.

Comment: After maximizing, If i click on DAM link, my ckeditor is disappearing and it is displaying page preview.